# Safest road route from Tangier to Togo

Tags: safety, driving, routes, africa, tangier

A local NGO that is working with Togo is going to organize a convoy (2 trucks) to bring some educational and medical aid. They will enter to Africa through Tangier, Morocco and are going to drive to Togo. What's the safest route possible? Also if you know some tips to make it safer, it will be very helpful.

Comment: fantastic question, about time we got some good African ones.

Comment: as an aside, are you involved in the trip? How'd you get into this?  Working with an NGO in such efforts appeals greatly.

Comment: Haven't you considered to send the material per ship? It will be safer and probably cheaper.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I've been involved in the past, not in this project, but I'd like to help with the "planning" part :)

Comment: @lejohn: Yes, but the trucks are part of the cooperation material (don't return).

Comment: OK, but trucks can be shipped too, together with their freight. You might even find a carrier who is willing to sponsor it.

Comment: @lejohn: Yes, of course, but the price is higher than driving. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, there are experienced travellers who have done these sorts of trips in the past.

The various roads in Africa sometimes form together to make the [Trans-African Highway Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-African_Highway_network).  When possible, using these would be optimal as they'd be more serviced, more frequented, better condition roads, and arguably safer.

[image: Trans-African highways]

You'd be joining Route 1 initially, down to Dakar.  A mainly coastal route continuing down the Atlantic coast of North-West Africa; substantially completeTAH 1 joins with TAH 7 to form an additional north-south route around the western extremity of the continent.

You'd be continuing on this TAH 7 route, also known as the Trans–West African Coastal Road, which is about 80% complete. Roads still exist in the incomplete stages, just not necessarily of highway standard.

This should take you all around to Togo.

---

The other option is Route 2 down through the desert.  This is probably faster and would have less border problems - except for one big one - the Algeria / Morocco border is currently closed.  This leaves you with the only realistic option being to head down the afore-mentioned coastal route.

Comment: It is easy to join Algeria from Europe. The argument against route 2 are serious safety concerns regrading southern Algeria. Caution is also advised in Niger. When using route 7, you have to monitor the situation in Casamance.

Comment: @lejohn - except that they've already organised (and specified) in the question that they're entering Africa in Tangier, so with the closed border, route 2 just isn't possible.  But probably a good thing, considering the safety concerns, as you mention :)

Comment: Route to is a no-go at the moment. I talked to people I know who travelled the route a couple of times, a closed border is not necessarily a problem in the middle of the Sahara... rebels who kidnap tourist are a show stopper however.

Comment: Perfect, I also believe that TAH 1 is safer due the problems in Algeria and Niger. I'll recommend that route.